# Cannot push into a repository after its name was changed

Tags: github

The repository I was working on had its name changed (I guess this could be the problem).

I did [these steps](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-repository), the name is updated on my computer but when I tried to push something I got this message:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6xxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

after writing yes:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.118.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

trying again to push:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The repository was made by me and after that someone else changed its name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a GitHub issue (or an ssh issue), not a Git issue. Make sure GitHub recognizes your public key: `ssh -T git@github.com` should print `Hi <yourname>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` I've switched the tag from git to github.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the url?

```
$ git remote set-url origin new_url
```